# https:// with red line

Tags: http, https, hosting

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.
To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
Themes and styles also help keep your document coordinated. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, charts, and SmartArt graphics change to match your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme.
Save time in Word with new buttons that show up where you need them. To change the way a picture fits in your document, click it and a button for layout options appears next to it. When you work on a table, click where you want to add a row or a column, and then click the plus sign.
Reading is easier, too, in the new Reading view. You can collapse parts of the document and focus on the text you want. If you need to stop reading before you reach the end, Word remembers where you left off - even on another device.

Answer (score 2):

When the https portion of the URL in Chrome has a red line through it, there is a problem with the security of the site you are going to. To see exactly what the problem is, you need to click on the padlock and see the detailed connection info.

Detailed connection info is documented here.

If you see green padlock, then you've established a secure connection with a trusted site, and do not need to worry about MITM attacks.

If you see yellow bang, then the connection is unencrypted, and subject to MITM attacks.

If you see grey padlock or red padlock, then either the connection is only partially encrypted or it's encrypted with a party that's not trusted (e.g., a self signed cert, name mismatch, or imposter). In these cases you may be subject to a MITM attack.

With these last two, the level of exposure varies. It might be that the remote site is properly encrypted, but just happens to have a few "IMG SRC=http://..." tags that cause mixed content. That "mixed content" can be sniffed on the network. Or, it might be that you've gone to an impostor site "gooogle.com" instead of "google.com", and everything you send is encrypted but going to a malicious attacker. Or anywhere in between. The rule of thumb is, essentially, unless you understand why it's red, you shouldn't trust it.